# Is there a mathematical name for the point where $n/x=x$

Tags: derivatives, terminology, curves

Were the graph of the asymptotic function $n/x$ rotated counterclockwise about the origin $45^O$, its derivation point would be 0 at $\sqrt{n}$ rotated similarly about the y axis where $n/x=x$.

The inflection point has significance, viz the derivative is 0. Does the point where the asymptote curves have any significance? $n=1$ [image: Where asymptote curves]. Visually the point has significance but I'm wondering if it has mathematical significance.

**Answering this question as well as some links to relevant reading would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the point where $ f(x) = x $ is called the fixed point.  However what I think the term you are looking for is the "vertex" of the hyperbola.

This is the point where the two branches are the nearest to each other and is where a line draw between the two foci of the hyperbola crosses the hyperbola.